# DocumentBeforePrint does not fire for Envelope print for VBA in Word

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

I am trying to switch users to use a different printer for envelopes in Word.  If they create the envelope, then print it, it works great using DocumentBeforePrint.  However, this event is NOT fired when using the Print button on the dialog Mailings --> Envelopes.  Is there any event fired when this happens that I can catch?

thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

There is no event, as such, however...

It is possible to `Display`, `Execute` or `Show` Word's built-in dialog boxes. A number of the controls in these dialog boxes are exposed so that they can be set or read. And the button used to dismiss the dialog box returns a value that can be evaluated.

The list of exposed controls is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists-word). The `WdWordDialog` enumerator for envelopes is `wdDialogToolsCreateEnvelope`. The properties listed are for both envelopes and labels, keep that in mind when sorting through the possibilities. Note that there is *no* IntelliSense for these properties. (For .NET people reading this, the properties are accessed via late-binding, meaning C# *must* use PInvoke in order to work with them.)

To read the user's input, place the properties *after* the method; to make "default setting", place the properties *before* the method.

Dismissing this dialog box returns the following values:

- `0` Cancel (or the "X" button)
- `1` Print
- `2` Add to Document:

Since you need to do something *before* the print job is sent, you probably need to use `Display` rather than `Show`. Display does not execute the dialog box when the user dismisses it. Instead, it's necessary to capture the settings, do something with them, then `Execute` the the dialog box.

For example, the following code displays the dialog box to the user, capture's the delivery address typed into that box, then handles the various return values.

```
Sub PrintEnvelopes()
    Dim dlg As Word.Dialog
    Dim retVal As Long
    Dim recipAddress As String

    Set dlg = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsCreateEnvelope)
    With dlg
        retVal = .Display
        recipAddress = .envaddress
    End With
    Select Case retVal
        Case 1 'Print
            With dlg
                'Change the printer here
                .envaddress = recipAddress
                .Execute
            End With
        Case 0 'Cancel
        Case 2 'Add to document
            With dlg
                 .envaddress = recipAddress
                .Execute
            End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, and would have used this if I hadn't found the info on catching the Envelope tools open.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there are events you can place in a module to intercept the Envelope tool launch (h/t http://www.gmayor.com/fax_from_word.htm).  As such, I added the following to one of my modules, and it runs when Mailings-->Envelopes is selected, so I can switch the printer, load the dialog, then switch the printer back after the dialog is finished:

```
Sub ToolsCreateEnvelope()

Dim DoChangePrinter As Boolean
Dim OriginalPrinterName As String
DoChangePrinter = False

OriginalPrinterName = Application.ActivePrinter
CurrentPrinterName = OriginalPrinterName

//Change to use color if on B&W printer
If InStr(1, LCase(CurrentPrinterName), "b&w") Then
    CurrentPrinterName = Replace(CurrentPrinterName, "B&W", "COLOR")
    DoChangePrinter = True
End If
If (DoChangePrinter) Then ChangePrinter

Application.ActiveDocument.Envelope.DefaultOmitReturnAddress = True

//Show dialog
Dim oDlg As Dialog
Set oDlg = Dialogs(wdDialogToolsCreateEnvelope)
With oDlg 'Pop up the envelopes dialog
.extractaddress = True
.Show
End With

    ActivePrinter = OriginalPrinterName 'Restore the original printer
End Sub
```

Comment: Some additional info: 1) This is intercepting the built-in command (not really "an event"). It originates from the WordBasic days. 2) This only works with Word VBA (code running in Word), it can't be leveraged for, say Excel or a .NET language.